# Actionscript 3 XML Menu With For Loop

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, menu, for-loop

I am trying to make a Xml Image Menu that on button click goes to specific frame label.

The Loop works, the Images and Text Loads without problems.

**My Problems:**

- The items don't center in stage (only
  the last xml item);
- On button click all the buttons goes 
  to the same Label (the label that is 
  on the last xml item);

**MY CODE:**

**Variables:**

```
//CREATE VARIABLES FOR XML
var columns:Number;
var my_total:Number;
var my_menu:XMLList;
var item_label:String;
var x_counter:Number = 0;
var y_counter:Number = 0;
```

**Load Xml, I Explain in comments everythings that works or not:**

```
//LOAD XML
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("xml.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    //DEFINE THE LENGTH OF THE MENU ITEMS (WORKS WELL)
    my_menu = myXML.ITEM;
    my_total = my_menu.length();
    columns = myXML. @ COLUMNS;

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++)
    {
        //CREATE THE LOOP FOR MOVIE CLIP THAT I HAVE IN LIBRARY WITH THE CLASS "menu_item" 
        var MC:MovieClip = new menu_item();
        var loadIMG:Loader = new Loader;
        // trace(MC); GIVE ME ALL THE XML ITEMS SO WORKS GOOD
        addChild(MC);

        //To CENTER ALL OBJECTS IN MC (NOT WORKS- ONLY CENTERS THE LAST ITEM OF THE XML)
        function resizeHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            MC.x = (MC.stage.stageWidth / 2) - (MC.width / 2);
            MC.y = (MC.stage.stageHeight / 2) - (MC.height / 2);
        }
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
        stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));

        //DISPLAY MENU ITEMS IN A GRID WITH COLUMNS (WORKS WELL)
        MC.x = (MC.width+10)*x_counter;
        MC.y = (MC.height+100)*y_counter;

        if (x_counter + 1 < columns)
        {
            x_counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            x_counter = 0;
            y_counter++;
        }

        //TO LOAD IMAGES AND TEXT FOR THE MENU (WORKS WELL)
        loadIMG.load(new URLRequest (my_menu[i].@IMAGE));
        MC.container_mc.img_mc.addChild(loadIMG);
        MC.container_mc.title_mc.text = my_menu[i]. @ TITLE;

        //TEST
        MC.name = "mc" + i;
        loadIMG.name = "image" + i;

        //ON BUTTON CLICK GO TO LABEL NAME IN XML (NOT WORKS, ALL ITEMS GOES TO THE SAME AND LAST LABEL IN XML)
        MC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);

        //var test = my_menu[i.target.name].@LABEL; //(FAILED TEST TO TARGET THE LABELS)
        var go_labels = my_menu[i]. @ LABEL;

        function callFull(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            labels_mc.gotoAndStop(go_labels);

        }


    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<MENU COLUMNS="2">
    <ITEM IMAGE="img/1.jpg" TITLE="title 1" LABEL="label 1"></ITEM> 
    <ITEM IMAGE="img/2.jpg" TITLE="title 2" LABEL="label 2"></ITEM> 
    <ITEM IMAGE="img/3.png" TITLE="title 3" LABEL="label 3"></ITEM> 
    <ITEM IMAGE="img/4.png" TITLE="title 4" LABEL="label 4"></ITEM>                         
</MENU>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should remove the functions from the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of errors in your code, tried to fix them quickly, see below and let me know how it works now.

```
//CREATE VARIABLES FOR XML
var columns:Number;
var my_total:Number;
var my_menu:XMLList;
var item_label:String;
var x_counter:Number = 0;
var y_counter:Number = 0;

//LOAD XML
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("xml.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    //DEFINE THE LENGTH OF THE MENU ITEMS (WORKS WELL)
    my_menu = myXML.ITEM;
    my_total = my_menu.length();
    columns = myXML. @ COLUMNS;

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++)
    {
        //CREATE THE LOOP FOR MOVIE CLIP THAT I HAVE IN LIBRARY WITH THE CLASS "menu_item" 
        var MC:MovieClip = new menu_item();
        MC.id = i;
        MC.label = my_menu[i]. @ LABEL;
        MC.name = "mc" + i;

        //DISPLAY MENU ITEMS IN A GRID WITH COLUMNS (WORKS WELL)
        MC.x = (MC.width+10)*x_counter;
        MC.y = (MC.height+100)*y_counter;

        if (x_counter + 1 < columns)
        {
            x_counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            x_counter = 0;
            y_counter++;
        }

        var loadIMG:Loader = new Loader;
        loadIMG.name = "image" + i;

        MC.container_mc.img_mc.addChild(loadIMG);
        MC.container_mc.title_mc.text = my_menu[i]. @ TITLE;

        addChild(MC);

        //ON BUTTON CLICK GO TO LABEL NAME IN XML (NOT WORKS, ALL ITEMS GOES TO THE SAME AND LAST LABEL IN XML)
        MC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
        //TO LOAD IMAGES AND TEXT FOR THE MENU (WORKS WELL)
        loadIMG.load(new URLRequest (my_menu[i].@IMAGE));

    }

    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
    stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));   
}

    function callFull(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //e.currentTarget should return the MC instance you clicked
        e.currentTarget.labels_mc.gotoAndStop(e.currentTarget.label);

    }

    //To CENTER ALL OBJECTS IN MC (NOT WORKS- ONLY CENTERS THE LAST ITEM OF THE XML)
    function resizeHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        var i:uint = 0;
        for (; i < my_total; i++ )
        {
            this["mc" + i].x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - this["mc" + i].width / 2;
            this["mc" + i].y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - this["mc" + i].height / 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a error in this line: (this["mc" + i].x = stage.stageWidth / 2) - (this["mc" + i].width / 2);

Comment: Sorry, you don't need the braces.
this["mc" + i].x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - this["mc" + i].width / 2;
this["mc" + i].x = stage.stageHeight / 2 - this["mc" + i].height / 2;

Comment: Without braces still give me a error in the same line. TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefiened and have no properties...

Comment: function resizeHandler(e:Event):void
     {
      var i:uint = 0;
      for (; i < my_total; i++ )
      {
       this["mc" + i].x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - this["mc" + i].width / 2;
       this["mc" + i].y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - this["mc" + i].height / 2;
      }
     }

Comment: But If I put the Resize Handler in comments I have the same error in the callFull function when I click in buttons, the problem could be here..

Comment: Don't comment the resizeHandler. Try to trace the e.currentTarget in callFull.

Comment: The e.currentTarget gives me [object menu_item] , and the e.currentTarget.label gives me the labels name, I think its right. The OutPut: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at main_es_test_fla::MainTimeline/resizeHandler()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.display::Stage/dispatchEvent()
 at main_es_test_fla::MainTimeline/processXML()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: Ok, try MovieClip(this.getChildByName("mc" + i)) instead of this["mc" + i].

Comment: This works but centers all items, so I just see one item, others are back,I need to centers like if I have all items inside a container. Thanks for the time spend to help...

Comment: then put the MC items into a container clip and set the position of the container. Leave the for loop of course in the resizeHandler. No worries.

Comment: Ok I'll do that, one more thing, on item's click gives me Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. I don't understand because the trace in e.currentTarget gives me the right values...

Comment: try to trace these: MovieClip(e.currentTarget).label, MovieClip(e.currentTarget).labels_mc.

Comment: Works with pages_mc.gotoAndStop(e.currentTarget.label);

Comment: I want to tell labels_mc.gotoAndStop(e.currentTarget.label); :)